# Is a set that consists of a single point connected?

Tags: connectedness, philosophy

If $S=\{a\}$ then surely for every two points from that set there is a path that joins them, choose $x_1=a$ and $x_2=a$ and define continuous function on $[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=a$. Or, one point cannot be represented as union of two or more disjoint nonempty open subsets.

What would happen if we would consider one-point set as neither connected nor disconnected (or both connected and disconnected)?

Is this situation similar to "should $1$ be considered prime or not"?

Comment: 1 not being prime is partly about decomposition: you don't want numbers to have infinitely many prime factorizations.  A connected set has connected components, and in that way a space can be decomposed.  If anything, the empty set should be the 1 of connected spaces, yet the empty set is nevertheless connected because it's not disconnected.

Answer (score 5):

Your first paragraph conflates "connectedness" and "path connectedness"; they're not the same.

For the second paragraph, this is like asking, "What if we said 2 was the same as $\pi$?" Your proposed "thing to say" might be amusing, but it contradicts both of the definitions of connectedness, for all possible topologies. So it's not very helpful.

I guess it's a little like the "is 1 prime" question, in the sense that there appears to be a widely accepted definition with which you have some qualms.

Let me add a little detail. We could say "a set $X$ is connected if (a) $X$ does not consist of a single point, and (b) for every pair of disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U \cup V = X$, one of $U$ or $V$ is empty." And we could define "disconnected" similarly, and then observe that one-point sets are neither connected nor disconnected.

The result would be that virtually every proof about connectedness would have an extra paragraph to say something about 1-point sets, or exclude 1-point sets in some way. I don't believe that this would lead to greater insight.

Comment: Let me mostly uselessly add: single-point spaces are locally path connected, so in this case they happen to be the same :-)

Comment: I was going to put that in, but I couldn't recall the exact characteristic that made the two agree. Thanks for refreshing my aging brain. :)

Comment: But what if I would tell you that I am onto a proof of some claim and that it depends on how we treat one-point sets, as connected or not? In this context it becomes important are they or are they not connected. At least for me only, if even that.

Comment: Then you should define "A-connected" as "connected as usual, but exceluding 1-point sets" ("A" is for "Antoine"), prove your theorem, and let all the world admire it. If it's really a big deal, maybe we'll all decide that the definition we've liked for the last 100 years really isn't all that great, and switch to using yours. That's how new terminology arises!

Comment: @AntoinePalAdeen There are plenty of theorems with multiple hypotheses: "If $X$ is a connected space *with more than one point*, [stuff]" is a perfectly reasonable form for a theorem to have. So you'll still have your theorem, regardless. The only thing this convention will affect is how your theorem is *stated*, and getting a slightly slicker theorem statement isn't worth changing terminology (let alone this piece of terminology, which is quite reasonable).

Answer (score 3):

As you've correctly demonstrated, the definition of connectedness resp. path-connectednes applies perfectly fine to the one-point space. So there is really no need to make an exemption. I also would not draw the analogy to the *Is $1$ prime?-* Question because in this case there are just no arguments for the one-point-space not to be path-connected.

Moreover one likes to think about path-connectedness as a property not only of spaces but also of homotopy classes of spaces. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#Homotopy_equivalence)
For example the one-point-set is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (and by definition also to every other contractible space). So if you want to consider euclidean space as path-connected, then you should also consider the one-point-space as path-connected.